# "Incorrect" entitlements when checking binary details in itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store, keychain, entitlements

I recently uploaded an app to the apple store and its current status is waiting for review.

I was checking the binary details to check everything was right but I read something that worried me.

In the Entitlements section I have the following:

get-task-allow: false

keychain-access-groups: ( "NN7NPDH5Z7.com.gears.awesomeapp" )

com.apple.developer.team-identifier: NN7NPDH5Z7

application-identifier: NN7NPDH5Z7.com.gears.awesomeapp

My app doesn´t use keychain anywhere, so what´s the reason for those entitlements appearing? I don´t have any entitlements plists either.

Can that be a cause of rejection?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are defaults, no need to worry.